# Unable to receive response from TIdTCPServer using TIdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, indy, tcpserver

I want to establish a communication between `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdTCPClient` in delphi and this is how my procedures look :
1.Server side :

```
procedure TMainForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  clientReq, clientName : String;
begin
  clientReq := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(); // client sends request
  clientName := extractClientName(clientReq);  
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Hello ' + clientName);
end;
```

2.Client side :

```
procedure TMainForm.btnTestClientClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  testTCP : TIdTCPClient;
  clientReq, serverResponse : String;
begin
  testTCP := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  try
    testTCP.Host := wantedHost;
    testTCP.Port := wantedPort;
    testTCP.Connect;
    clientReq := 'Hello, my Name is user1.';
    testTCP.IOHandler.WriteLn(clientReq);
    try
      serverResponse := testTCP.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    except on e : Exception do begin
      ShowMessage('Error reading response =' + e.Message);
    end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(testTCP);
  end;
end;
```

I connect to the server but than my application freezes when I try to receive the response from the server `OnExecute` event with my `TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn` method. Can anyone help me fix my code or show me a working example of what I'm trying to do (with Indy's `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown, so the problem has to be in the code you have not shown.  The way I see it, there are two possibilities:

1. If you are not setting `wantedHost` and/or `wantedPort` to the correct values, you would not actually be connecting to your expected server.
2. If `extractClientName()` is getting stuck internally and not exiting, the server would not be sending any response. One way that could happen is if you are running the client and server in the same process, and `extractClientName()` syncs with the main thread, but the main thread is blocked waiting on the client and cannot process the sync, so a deadlock occurs.

Comment: Yes, blocking the main thread was the problem, but it wasn't coming from `extractClientName()` but from `serverResponse := testTCP.IOHandler.ReadLn();`

Comment: That is normal. `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. Its `OnExecute` event runs in a worker thread. `testTCP.IOHandler.ReadLn()` is blocking the main thread waiting for the server thread to call `WriteLn()`. That would not happen if `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn()` blocks/fails, or if `extractClientName()` blocks/fails. If `OnExecute` raises an uncaught exception, the client is disconnected and `testTCP.IOHandler.ReadLn()` would then raise an exception. You are not seeing that happen, so that still suggests that `extractClientName()` is likely blocking and not exiting.

Comment: Can you please show the code for `extractClientName()`?

Comment: It was actually all for testing - without `extractClientName()` the application was still freezing - I just added it to my question so that it wouldn't look too primitive. My real `OnExecute` event looked like this :
   `clientReq := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();`
   `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Hello user1.');`

Comment: Now after I know why my application freezes I can easily write my procedures who will extract the needed data from the client's request and send suitable response. :)